# How to store and import static files in React Native?

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I would like to store static *.txt, *.svg, and even *.js files in a React Native project (clean, without any Expo and other wrappers, Webpacks, using Babel only) in `assets` folder (or other commonly preferred path). Then I would like to import them into the App.js as strings. There is so much contradictory info on the topic. How do I properly do that in a brand new app?

Comment: I guess if your asset is being accessed by different locations in your code ... then the best location is the `assets` folder ... if it's only related to a specific piece of code ... then you could place it in the same folder of that js file (your component folder for example) ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli But how do I import it? My current solution is to place file content into JSON file looking like `{ "value": "..." }` and then doing `import {value} from './assets/file.json'`. I expect to do something like `const value = ReactNative.loadResource('./assets/file.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})`.

Comment: let me reply in an answer to be more readable...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a json file like:

```
const data = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
};

export default data;
```

The only way to access your data is through:

```
import data from '../your/relative/path/to/data';
```

If you want to import specific key in that file, then your json file would be somthing like that:

```
export const key1 = 'value1';
export const key2 = 'value2';

const data = {
    key1,
    key2,
};

export default data;
```

Now you'd have the ability to do that:

```
import { key1 } from '../your/relative/path/to/data';
```

**OR**

```
import data from '../your/relative/path/to/data';
```

I suggest for **text** files, you store them in a `constants` folder, and make a a relevant `.js` file for each category:

constants.js file:

```
export const CONST_KEY_1 = 'some value';
export const CONST_KEY_2 = 'some other value';
export default {
    CONST_KEY_1,
    CONST_KEY_2
};
```

And for svg file:

Fast approach: to store the `file_uri` of each file in a key value pair in the same way we did in the constants.js file

Better approach: to store `svg path` of these svg files in the same form we did in the constants.js file ... and render these files using react-native-svg npm module.

Comment: But I would like to store static *.txt, *.svg, and even *.js files and use them as string values.

Comment: and you know the content of these files in advance ? ... I mean at compile time not the run-time

Comment: Yes, these are static files.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. To follow your advice I think I will have to generate JS files inserting text content and making escaping of some symbols, JSON.stringify should do it. I will accept your answer if there will be no other solutions.

Comment: That's what I usually do ... and keep in mind that in order to load any file using `require` for example ... you're going to need a `string literal for each file uri`, so I guess listing your `uris` in a constants file would make sens ... and you're welcome after all whether my suggestion suits your case or not...

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try [Babel Plugin Inline Import](https://github.com/feats/babel-plugin-inline-import) which is designed to do exactly this. Just be aware of issues with the babel cache keeping old versions of your text files around, if you make changes to them.