# How to access static/local files in react native

Tags: file-io, react-native

I'm not sure what to call the files, but the context is that I have a bunch of data that I would like to ship with my app. I need to find a way to store this data so that I can load it into the database. (Or better yet, just ship it with a prefilled db)

Here are the solutions that I've seen:

[Storing the data in code as a json blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431026/how-to-store-and-import-static-files-in-react-native) I can't do this because I have quite a lot of data, a few MB or so and I would like to be able to compress it.

[Load a file from the public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486116/how-to-import-file-from-public-folder-in-react-application)
I think this is a create-react-app specific API and I did not use that. But if there's a way to get a public or static folder to read arbitrary files from, that'll be great.

[Read a file using react-native-fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206916/how-to-store-read-static-content-data-in-react-native-expo)
I'm not sure where to put the file in my application so that I can access it. This seems to give me an empty folder to write files to. I don't know where in my app directory I can put the files if I want it to be read by this.

I would also like to have these files compressed, and only loaded when I need them to be. I think using a `require('path/to/file.json')` loads the file every time I use the app.

How would I go about reading a file from my app?

I'm coding for android if that matters and the database I'm using is watermelondb.

Comment: Are you able to get the uri for the file that you want to upload?

Comment: I'm not trying to upload a file, just to read it. The problem is I don't know where to put the file in my project so that I can access it.

Comment: If you want to just show the PDF, I'd prefer not to download it and instead show it using some libraries like [react-native-pdf](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onpress) to view.

Comment: This is not a PDF. I'm trying to store a compressed file that I can load into my database on first run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [react-native-asset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset) to put files to your project and access them with `require` keyword.

Example for file with path `./assets/files/some-file.mp3`:

1. Add or modify `react-native.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
 project: {
   ios: {},
   android: {},
 },
 dependencies: {
 },
 assets: [
   './assets/files'
 ],
};
```

2. Run `npx react-native-asset`
3. Use the file:

```js
const file = require('./assets/files/some-file.mp3')
```